# Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char'))

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

After updating my project to 10.7 SDK and switching debugger,
I got this message:

```
Property with 'iboutlet' attribute must be an object type (invalid 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char'))
```

It was perfectly working before the update.
Any hint on how to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to import the map framework (MapKit/MapKit.h)

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using custom classes for components (i.e. subclassing from UI*) remember that you need to import the .h file for your class so your property pointer is not just an (id) for the compiler.

Comment: You are right, I'm using #import "BOValidationTextField.h". I have imported this .h file in my class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unlink and link again the IBOutlet, or try to assign the `boolValue` to that variable holding the object.

As far as i know, with the new SDK many things are becoming deprecates and things won't work properly. That's why i hate using beta's!

Answer (score 1):

IBOutlets are always objects, they are values that are referenced in xibs/nibs, you can't really do that with scalar values. If you need to set a boolean then you can call a setter in an object's -awakeFromNib method, or depending on what you are doing: kvo or delegation  may be appropriate.